# Why do I get different estimates in MatchIt in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to implement nearest-neighbor matching using MatchIt in R.

I get different estimates for difference in means whenever I run the following code:

```
library(MatchIt)
mout <- matchit(treat ~ age, data=lalonde, method="nearest")
mdata <- match.data(mout, distance="pscore")
with(mdata, t.test(re78[treat==1], re78[treat==0], paired=TRUE))
```

Can anyone see why?

I thought about any option to fix randomization in matchit(), but tyring different options for `m.order` and `exact` doesn't seem to solve my problem.